# How to read the archived JSON file & pass a parameter to the next job?

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

I could able to fetch an archived file by copy articrafts from another project.
This archived file is in JSON. I need to extract a value from this JSON file and pass this parameter to the next build. I've used python script to do that (Execute Shell), but scope of that variable is not visible outside Execute Shell. Is there any other way, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could pass the parameter off to the next build is by using the Jenkins API in a Groovy postbuild step.

For example, here is a quick script that will:

1. Read in an archived json file called "myJsonFile.json" (assuming it lies in the root of the workspace)
2. Kick off a job called "myDownstreamJob" passing in the value of "myJsonParameter" (found within that "myJsonFile.json" file) for the build parameter named "Param1" in the downstream job.

---

```
// Parse the json file
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(new File(manager.build.artifactsDir.path + "\\myJsonFile.json"))

// Get the target json value
def myValue = json.myJsonParameter

// Kick off downstream job passing in json value as Param1
manager.hudson.getItem("myDownstreamJob").scheduleBuild(5, new hudson.model.Cause.UpstreamCause(manager.build), new hudson.model.ParametersAction([ new hudson.model.StringParameterValue( "Param1", myValue ) ]));
```